# Whats the different between source table and LASR Server table?

Tags: sas, analytics, sas-macro, sas-visual-analytics

I'm new to SAS Visual Analytics and I'm asking me, what exactly is the SAS LASR Analytic Server? I have read a lot of websites and for me, it looks like, that the SAS LASR Analytic Server is a component that I can use to load data from source tables into in RAM. But where is my data stored when I load a CSV table into Visual Analytics Source Table? Thing is, I come from QlikView and there is all the data always in memory.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LASR is SAS's previous-gen in-memory analytics engine that can either be distributed or single-server. When you load a CSV into LASR, it is converted into a special format and stored on the LASR analytic server. If you have a distributed setup, your data is distributed in-memory among your worker nodes.

You can access your data via the `SASIOLA` engine and a data step and use it just like any other SAS engine. High Performance procedures such as `PROC HPSUMMARY`, `PROC HPLOGISTIC`, and `PROC HPDS2`will take advantage of tables in LASR and perform very fast calculations on them. [PROC IMSTAT](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=inmsref&docsetTarget=n1l5k6bed95vzqn1a47vafe3q958.htm&docsetVersion=2.83&locale=en) can create statistical models in-memory, among other things.

You cannot overwrite LASR tables: they must first be dropped and then reloaded. You can, however, append, delete, and update rows using `PROC IMSTAT`; in my experience, it's just easier to drop and reload tables unless you have very specialized report uptime requirements.

Tables cannot be accessed from Visual Analytics without first [registering it to Metadata.](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Visual-Analytics/Adding-and-registering-table-to-LASR-in-SAS-VA/td-p/423566) VA will automatically handle this for you if you load data directly.

Your data will stay in-memory within LASR until the server reboots or the table is dropped. Unlike Cloud Analytic Services (CAS) in Viya, LASR does not do automatic on-demand loading. Instead, you can set up an [Autoload directory](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/vapdbgwin/68972/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0g0cxn6tnn9yqn1kuc0edx1xgin.htm) that will automatically update and refresh tables in LASR. SAS tables, Excel, and .csv files you drop there will automatically be picked up and loaded every 15 minutes. This is a good way to ensure your data is available after reboots, as it will scan this directory and load data.

In general, my process has been this:

1. Copy data to Autoload
2. Load data to LASR

If you are lucky enough to have co-located Hadoop, you can store your data as a `sashdat` file and load data extremely quickly into LASR. In essence ,`sashdat` is LASR format on-disk. Data can be automatically loaded into memory on reboot from there, but it will not behave the same as Autoload.

[Cloud Analytic Services](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2018/08/13/intro-cas-sas-viya/) (CAS) has superseded LASR in recent years and builds heavily off of its existing features.